# Java Spring ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, pool

If I configure ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean with maxPoolSize=1 - so executor always has 1 thread - if I run 2 or more threads - spring create some queue or next invocation will wait previous?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the maxPoolSize is 1, then only one thread will run at the same time, so only one task will be executed at the same time.  However, the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) has a queue, so any tasks that are not executed immediately will be done asynchronously when a thread becomes available.

So when you have an ThreadPoolExecutor with maxPoolSize 1, the following code will return immediately

```
executor.execute(runnable1);
executor.execute(runnable2);
```

and runnable1 will be executed in the thread first, once that's finished, runnable2 will be executed.